# How can I modify a Perl DateTime object?

Tags: perl, datetime, date

In my script I need to make a cycle like this one:

```
use DateTime;
for $j(0..3){
    my ($date) = DateTime->now->ymd;
    my ($k) = 0;
    while($k <= $j){
        $date = ($date->subtract( days => 7));
        $k++;
    }
print "$date\n";
}
```

which should get the current date, then one week ago, etc. Sadly, after getting the correct current date, it doesn't work and I don't know what's wrong.

```
Error message is "Can't call method "subtract" without a package or object reference [...]",
```

but I have no idea how to fix this.

If possible, I'd like to keep using DateTime only OR replacing it with another module (possibly no more than one).

Comment: Sorry, wrote it without copying. $i is $j.

Comment: That while loop is better written `for (0 .. $j) { ... }`

Comment: `DateTime` *subtract* method updates the object. So `$date = ...` is superfluous and so the line could just be: `$date->subtract( days => 7 );`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Datetime->now->ymd` is a scalar (string, it appears), not an object/reference. You can't call `subtract` on it because it doesn't exist. You'll probably just want to try omitting the `ymd` part when you assign to `$date`:

```
my ($date) = DateTime->now;
...

for(0..$j) {
    $date = ($date->subtract( days => 7));
}

...
```

If you want to access the `ymd` value, do it after you've created the object:

```
my ($date) = DateTime->now;
...
my ($ymd) = $date->ymd;
```

See the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.63/lib/DateTime.pm) page for more.

Comment: Yep, I messed that up. =) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you tried using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) on `$date` you would immediately see what the problem is: `$date` is a string, not an object. You should delay calling `ymd()` on it until you need to stringify it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

for my $j (0..3)
{
    my $date = DateTime->now;
    $date = $date->subtract(days => 7) for (0 .. $j);
    print $date->ymd, "\n";
}
```

PS. This code can be simplified even more by combining the loops:

```
my $date = DateTime->now;
for my $weeks (0..4)
{
    print $date->ymd, "\n";
    $date = $date->subtract(days => 7);    
}
```

Comment: Is it just this week, or has there been a steady acculumation of questions by people who don't even bother to inspect values or try anything to debug their problems? It seems really odd to me because in most cases, the level of skill of the questioner seems to indicate they should know this stuff.

Comment: @brian: there does seem to be a bit of an uptick lately. I wonder if it is to do with the new school year starting (in the northern hemisphere).

Answer (score 3):

It's better to do the ymd when printing, after the calculations and working on the Date object.

See the difference when switching when `ymd` and `subtract` are called:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    

use strict;    
use Data::Dumper;
use DateTime;

   sub main{   
      my $date = DateTime->now->subtract(days=>7)->ymd;
      print "$date\n\n";
   }    

   main();
```